# How do I use regex to replace periods in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript.

I have a string:

```
let x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\""; // .175" x 2.5" x 144"
```

I would like to manipulate the string to return 3 separate variables

```
var thickness = 0.175
var width = 2.5
var length = 144
```

I need to change the thickness in the string from .175 to 0.175, here is my attempt:

```
     let x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\"";
    let regex = / /g;
    let regex2 = /\./i;
    let regex3 = /\"/g;
    //Do the regex function

    const regexFun = () => {
        try {
            console.log(x);
            if (x.charAt(0) == "."){
                const fun1 = x.replace(regex2, '0.'); 
                console.log(fun1);
            }
            else{

                const fun1 = x.replace(regex3, '');
                console.log(fun1);
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
```

In the example I gave I can delete the quotes using " but it doesn't seem to work with . How can I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking at this from the wrong angle. Just create a regular expression that extracts the numeric values and then convert them to number values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Felix commented, best way may be to extract your numbers using regex first and then parse them as floats:

```js
var x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\""; // .175" x 2.5" x 144"

let numbers = x.match(/(\d*\.)?\d+/g).map(n => parseFloat(n))

var thickness = numbers[0]
var width = numbers[1]
var length = numbers[2]

console.log('thickness: ' + thickness)
console.log('width: ' + width)
console.log('length: ' + length)
```

Comment: This approach would be perfect, but I have no idea what's happening here, could you please explain the regex expression, Ty!

Comment: @Vanillaice, here is a link to the regex. I think this may help you decipher it more effectively then me trying to explain it here :) https://regex101.com/r/h1uwU1/1

Answer (score 1):

You could match the format of the string with named capture groups.

```
^(?<thickness>\d*\.?\d+)"\s+x\s+(?<width>\d*\.?\d+)"\s+x\s+(?<length>\d*\.?\d+)"$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<thickness>\d*\.?\d+)` Group *thickness* match optional digits, optional dot and 1+ digits
- `"\s+x\s+` Match `"` and an `x` char between optional whitespace chars
- `(?<width>\d*\.?\d+)` Group *width* with the same digits pattern
- `"\s+x\s+` Match the `"` and `x` char
- `(?<length>\d*\.?\d+)` Group *length* with the same digits pattern
- `"` Match literally
- `$` End of string

See the group values on a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lfkeMk/1).

```js
let x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\"";
const regex = /^(?<thickness>\d*\.?\d+)"\s+x\s+(?<width>\d*\.?\d+)"\s+x\s+(?<length>\d*\.?\d+)"$/;
const m = x.match(regex);

if (m) {
  const thickness = parseFloat(m.groups.thickness);
  const width = parseFloat(m.groups.width);
  const length = parseFloat(m.groups.length);
  console.log(thickness, width, length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex

`(^|\D)(\.\d+)`

```
(         // Begin capture
    ^     // Beginning of line
    |     // Or
    \D    // Any non-digit
)         // End capture
(         // Begin capture
    \.    // Decimal point
    \d+   // Number
)         // End capture
```

Replace with `$10$2`

```
$1        // Contents of the 1st capture
0         // Literal 0
$2        // Contents of the 2nd capture
```

```js
let x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\"";
console.log(x.replace(/(^|\D)(\.\d+)/g, "$10$2"));
```

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/TjahIa/1)

Answer (score 0):

try using `split()` and `parseFloat`

```js
let x = ".175\" x 2.5\" x 144\"";

const regexFun = () => {
  numbers = x.split('x').map(n=>parseFloat(n))
  console.log(numbers)
}
regexFun()
```